# Text book for mathematical economics?

Tags: mathematical-economics

I need a text book for mathematical economics with real world examples. Currently I'm using A.C Chiang (very good) and Henderson and Quandt ( not the best book for matheco). Can someone recommend any others ?

Comment: Is this for upper/lower tier undergraduate, masters, PhD, or post-PhD level?

Comment: Undergraduate study

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chiang is probably the best you can find, but you might try Takayama - Mathematical Economics or Simon and Blume - Mathematics for Economists.